# How do I pass List<T> type from one action to another action in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying like

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Name = Name });
```

where name is string type. and it is working but how do I pass list to another action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this would help http://jonkruger.com/blog/2009/04/06/aspnet-mvc-pass-parameters-when-redirecting-from-one-action-to-another/